# Is there a way to call a function when user enters the website/link?

Tags: python, django

So basically I'm working on a project that will allow users to download vCard when they enter the link. For example: https://www.google.com, when users open the link, a vCard will be downloaded.
I already have the download method written in views.py. and I want it to be executed when users open the link.

I tried to search on the internet, but I got no result.

This is the method to open the link:

```py
def shareContact(request, data):
    try:
        cardDetails = uservcfDetails.objects.all().filter(uuid=data)
        cardID = uservcfDetails.objects.get(uuid=data)

        userID = cardID.user_id_id
        checkBalance = userExchangeBalance.objects.get(user_id_id=userID)


        context = {
            'details': cardDetails,
        }
        return render(request, 'webapp/VCFCard/shareContact.html', context)
    except Exception as error:
        return render(request, 'webapp/VCFCard/CardNotFound.html')
```

I also have another method to download the file:

```py
def download(request):
    ...
    return
```

My question is: how to call the download method automatically?

Comment: Your question is unclear. When users click on google.com, they will be taken to Google.

Comment: @DanielRoseman https:www.google.com is only for an example. what i meant is that, when a user entered the website that i created(shareContact), i want the download function to be executed.

Comment: That's still not clear. Enter it how? And if you want to call `download` from `shareContact`, why can't you just do so?